# Spark : Split input into multiple Arrays

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Being new to spark and scala. I need to check how I can achieve this:

input:`val x = sc.parallelize(1 to 10, 3)`

o/p after collecting:

```
Array[Int] = Array(1,2,3,4,5))

Array[Int] = Array(2,4,6,8,10)
```

Comment: what's the logic? what have you tried?

Comment: Can you describe what operation your trying to do. Im not sure why the numbers in the array might be changing.

Comment: looks like you might want  `Array(1,2,3,4,5).map(_ + 1)`

Comment: I'm backing @mtoto 's questions. We can't read minds. Please show us to you are putting some effort into your question.

Comment: Write the missing code in the given Scala program to display the output in the following format.

Program

val x = sc.parallelize(1 to 10, 3)

Array[Int] = Array(1,2,3,4,5))

Array[Int] = Array(2,4,6,8,10)

<Write your code>

y.collect

Comment: And what did you try already to solve that problem?

Comment: this doesnt look like odd even problem . i can solve with two rdd . But one single RDD i am not getting how to get Array[Int] = Array(1,2,3,4,5))

Array[Int] = Array(2,4,6,8,10)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for

```
val evens = x.filter(value => value % 2 == 0)
val odds = x.filter(value => value % 2 != 0)
```

Thanks

Outputs :

```
scala> evens.foreach(println)
4
6
2
8
10

scala> odds.foreach(println)
5
1
3
7
9
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this helps you to understand as per your question.

```
 val spark =
    SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("test").getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(1 to 10, 3)

  data.filter(_ < 6).collect().foreach(println)
```

Output

```
1
2
3
4
5

  data.filter(_%2 == 0).collect().foreach(println)
```

Output

```
2
4
6
8
10
```